# Bikesharing datasets

Tags: data-request, api, public-transport, bikesharing

Im trying to obtain historical datasets of public transports like train, bus and also bikesharing provider. While api.citybik.es provides almost all APIs of these providers, i struggle to actually find a database with compiled data throughout a year.
My big goal is to compare the capacity usage of two or more of these public transports in one city(preferably Germany).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

motivateco, the firm charged with operating the city's now-public Bike Share program, have a [list of XML and JSON feed](https://www.motivateco.com/use-our-data/) for each city they operate in. 
They also release the [General Bikeshare Feed Specification (GBFS)](https://github.com/NABSA/gbfs/blob/master/gbfs.md) which they are trying to push as a standard for bike sharing data publication.

If you are looking for time series data check out:

- [NYC Historical, Machine-readable Citibike Data](http://data.beta.nyc/dataset/historical-machine-readable-citibike-data)
- [DC Capital Bikeshare Dock History](http://www.opendatadc.org/dataset/capital-bikeshare-dock-history)

Answer (score 1):

[Capital Bikeshare's AWS server has data from 2010 4q - Current](https://s3.amazonaws.com/capitalbikeshare-data/index.html)
[Cambridge, MA has data from 2015 - Current](http://www.cambridgema.gov/CDD/Transportation/gettingaroundcambridge/bybike/biketrends)